# Windows 7 - WebDav - Disable “These files might be harmful to your computer” warning

Tags: windows-7, windows, webdav, owncloud

I am connecting Windows 7 clients to a file server via WebDAV. Clients can successfully map the drive, browse, and access files.

However, whenever a file is copied from the mapped drive to the local computer, Windows pops up the "These files might be harmful to your computer" warning dialog.

I have already added the server address (I tried both fqdn and ip address) to Local Intranet as discussed here

[Disable "These files might be harmful to your computer" warning?](https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning)

and set the security level for Local Intranet to LOW, but the warning still happens.

What else do I need to do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

is it mapped as a drive letter or network location? If it's a drive letter, this might work:

Run this as an Administrator from the command prompt and it will fix you issue without compromising your internet security.

ICACLS "X:\Path\To\Mapped\WebDAV" /Setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)M
Keep The quotes﻿ if spaces are in the path.