# Why does Windows report that files stored on my NAS might be harmful when I try to copy them?

Tags: windows, nas

**Scenario**

My NAS drive ([a Synology DS214+](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS214+)) not working on a domain, with multiple clients connected on the domain.

Network drive mounted and can be accessed, however copying files gives the following error:

[image]

This error was not present when the NAS drive was part of the domain, however this is no longer possible.

**Question**

1: Am I right in assuming that this error is because the NAS drive is not part of the domain, and the domain client is trying to access files?

2: Is there any other option to fix this other than rejoining the domain?

**Update**

- Mapping via the IP address or hostname makes no difference

Comment: If you're using the NAS's host name to map it, try using the IP instead (or vise versa).

Comment: Same error with both

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your questions...

1. **Am I right in assuming that this error is because the NAS drive is not part of the domain, and the domain client is trying to access files?**
   This error is probably caused by Windows thinking you're copying stuff from the Internet and not the intranet and depending on the security settings for the zone (probably the `Launching applications and unsafe files` setting?) it is prompting you to confirm the transfer.
   [image: Internet security settings]
2. **Is there any other option to fix this other than rejoining the domain?**
   [Yes](https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning). Add the IP address of the NAS drive to the Local Intranet zone. Bring up Internet Options by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → `control /name Microsoft.InternetOptions` → <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   Then follow [Jeff Atwood's instructions](https://superuser.com/a/149057/167187):

   - Click **Security** tab.
   - Click **Local Intranet**
   - Click **Sites** button.
   - Click **Advanced** button.
   - Enter the IP Address of the other machine or server (wildcards are allowed) and click **Add**
   - Click **Close**, then **OK**, then **OK** again.

     [image: Add to local intranet]

Comment: The 2nd part fixed the issue, however the PC doesn't have the prompt option ticked as per the 1st part.

Comment: @JB_STWUK I'm not really sure it's related to ur problem. What option did you have selected?

Comment: Enabled was selected

Comment: @JB_STWUK I see. I'm not really sure which security setting results in that prompt. It might be [this one](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/allow-files-from-this-website-to-be-copied-to-computer) but it doesn't matter once you've added your NAS drive to the local intranet zone.