# How to disable the "These files might be harmful to your computer" nag screen from CMD?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, unattended

I'm seeking to do exactly what is asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning), but from the command line. I'm performing an unattended installation of Windows 10 and wish to be able to execute a command or modify an entry in the registry to rid this:

[image]

Comment: You need to customize IE during the installation, which use to be done using Sysprep in customizing older version of Windows installations. I am sure those are just IE registry changes that need to be done during installation but do not know what they are.

Comment: I assume this prompt came from a file you accessed on a network/file share? Was it a certain file type? Context might help future users :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will simply need to add it to the registry. This is an export from a test I did, using 192.168.0.10:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges\Range1]
"*"=dword:00000001
":Range"="192.168.0.10"
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to use HKLM instead of HKCU, but I presume it's on a per user basis.

In terms of a command line:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges\Range1" /v "*" /t REG_DWORD /d "1"
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges\Range1" /v ":Range" /t REG_SZ /d "192.168.0.10"
```

Obviously change the IP to suit, and if you need more use `Range2`, `Range3` etc.