# These files might be harmful to your computer warning can't fix it? There is a post that I mentioned that had the same issue but it doesn't work

Tags: windows-10

I tried the method in this post "Disable “These files might be harmful to your computer” warning?" but it doesn't work. I tried all the solutions I found and it is not a duplicate because I just want to say that I tried all the method in that post, that's why I put it in reference.

How can I fix it?

This is the post: [Disable "These files might be harmful to your computer" warning?](https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjzqk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibHwR.png

Comment: There are several solutions in your link, did you try all of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable the "These files might be harmful to your computer" nag screen from CMD?](https://superuser.com/questions/1025856/how-to-disable-the-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-nag-screen-fr)

Comment: I tried all the solutions I found and it is not a duplicate because I just want to say that I tried all the method in that post, that's why I put it in reference. @Moab