# Local disk: "These files might be harmful to your computer"

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, security, popups, local-storage

When moving or copying files from my local harddisk, I get the message:

> These files might be harmful to your computer. Your internet security
>   settings suggest that one or more files may be harmful.

This happens when I move or copy files on the drive (D:) itself, or when I move/copy files from that drive to any another drive on my pc. All the drives are local installed in my case and connected with sata cables.

How can I disable or fix this pop-up message?

I am running: Windows 10, Version 1511,Os Build 10586.164, It's my own build machine. (I have seen a lot of similar posts, but in my case I am not transferring files over the internet)

**Update**

It has been a while I posted this question, and I still have this problem. I tried the suggestion from @manjesh23, but this did not work.

[image: pop-up]

Comment: I have that same message since a while. Seems Microsoft considers D: a part of the internet. - looking forward to a solution...

Comment: Would that mean changing the drive letter would solve the problem? I have seen it used before though.

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix by changing "internet options" -- so I guess Windows is detecting the "internet" as my own network.. sigh.

- Click Start / Control Panel / Internet Options
- Click **Security** tab.
- Click **Local Intranet**
- Click **Sites** button.
- Click **Advanced** button.
- Enter the IP Address of the other machine or server (wildcards are allowed) and click **Add**
- Click **Close**, then **OK**, then **OK** again.

[image: Changing Internet Options screenshot]

This worked for me, but it's a bummer I have to manually enter IPs here.. it would be nice if Windows could detect this is a local network file copy and skip the irritating (and pointless) warning about "dangerous" files.

[Source:](https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning)

Comment: Saw this a while back, but tried it again anyway. I added my IP but still get the warning. Also don't get why a local harddrive should have anything to to with intranet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the file properties and Unblock the file. Next, to mitigate this issue when you open downloaded files, do the following.

[More information on attachment manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/883260#bookmark-detail)

I prefer using group policies to fix this issue rather than messing with registry entries or internet settings. Just one way of doing it. However, this requires a suitable Windows version as not every edition provides this feature.

1. Click Start
2. Type gpedit.msc in the search area and press enter
3. Once it is open,expand User Configuration > Administrative templates > Windows Components and then click on Attachment Manager.
4. Now you will see the available options. I will provide a brief.

[image]

What you should change/enable/configure to fix the issue:

1. Do not preserve zone information in file attachments: If you enable this, this will remove the zone information from the file and fixing this issue. Your file system must be NTFS. If it is a Fat32, this does not work.
2. Or else, you can select the risk level. You could adjust this to suite your needs.
3. Or else, if you really want to customize based on file types, utilize the last 3 settings.
4. To refresh the gpo settings (to apply updates), start an elevated command prompt and run the following command: gpupdate /force

Remember. If you alter or disable or reduce the hardening which are there to ensure security, you increase the risk level, unless you know what you are doing.