# Disable "These files might be harmful to your computer" message for home server (Win10)

Tags: security, security-warning

I've just set up a small home server, and I'm getting a "These files might be harmful to your computer" message whenever accessing files on it. The solution I've found is to edit my internet options and add the server's IP to a trusted list, but the "Sites" button is grayed out, so I'm unable to edit it:

[Disable "These files might be harmful to your computer" warning?](https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning)

[image: Grayed out "Sites" option pic]

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You need to be an Administrator

Comment: My account is an administrator account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution on this site:
http://www.winhelponline.com/xp/ie/flags.htm

open regedit, go to
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1

find the "Flags" item, and whatever value is there, add "3" to it (i.e. if it's 0, change to 3; if it's 8, change to 11, etc) -- this enables both the "Sites" and "Custom settings" buttons

Then you can simply follow the steps in this solution to disable the notification for your server:
[Disable "These files might be harmful to your computer" warning?](https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning)