# Cannot open files from or copy too Google Drive Desktop & getting “These files might be harmful to your computer” warning when trying to copy them

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-file-stream

I'm using Google Drive for desktop and have a virtual drive on my computer where I can directly access Google docs without having to use the web UI.

In the settings I have it set to Stream, rather than  mirror files

When trying to work with non-native Google docs stored there, such as Word Docs, Powerpoint Docs, Excel sheets, PDFS, I'm having issues copying & opening the files:

1. If I try top open them from clicking them from virtual drive, I get an error message in their app:

[image]
[image]
[image]

2. When I copy them **from** the virtual drive to my computer I'm prompted with the “These files might be harmful to your computer” error message from windows.

[image]

3. When I try to open the copied file, I get the same error messages as in point 1.
4. If I try to copy news files **to** the Virtual Drive I get an error message from windows saying the file is not found. Yet its still there.

[image]

I found this support thread about a similar issue:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/error-message-when-opening-a-word-document/4b2b9673-079d-4010-ad6f-8e0986f2e76f

There are 2 recommendations

a. **To Unblock the file via the Properties.**

However, my files do not have this option:

[image]

b. **Disable Protected View in Trust Center Settings For MS products.**

However disabling this has no effect and doesn't help for non MS apps.

I also found this similar issue:  [Disable "These files might be harmful to your computer" warning?](https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning)

But it requires adding an IP address, so im wondering:

a. How do I find the IP address for Google virtual Drive?

b. Will this fix help my issue?

c. Why has it just started today, after 1 year of using Google drive desktop?

Comment: "Why has it just started today, after 1 year of using Google drive desktop?" - Google decided to change their application for the third time.  Be sure these files are actually downloaded to your machine instead of being available online.  You can just unblock the files by right-clicking and doing so within the properties of the file.  Attempting to unblock Google Drive by IP address would be a pointless endeavor since the address isn't static.

Comment: I don't store the files on my local machine, only in the Gdrive. I did see an article that said you can right click a file and unblock. However, I don't have the unblock option on any of the files.

Comment: Unless Google Drive is mounting the remote location, which used to take third-party software to do, then the file should still exist locally on the drive.

Comment: I have it set to 'stream files', rather than "mirror files". "Stream files: Store all My Drive files in the cloud only". "Mirror files: Store all My Drive files in the cloud and on your computer." So I presume they aren't on my local machine.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the different tabs of Properties on a file like test.txt by editing your question

Comment: Done, also discovered I cannot copy files to the virtual drive now either and added that to the question.

Comment: When I have in the past encountered a similar issue with OneDrive, I solved it by logging into the account, that had been inadvertently been logged out of. These were files that existed only online but placeholders we’re displayed